# Angular 4 : Change/convert newline in textarea to br (html view)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem in form input, specificly in textarea input. I need to convert/change newline to 
 in textarea input. How to change/convert it in component? I need to post that input to API

I dont know how to process that textarea input. I think I need to make a new function to processing that input. I'm trying so hard to solve that problem, but I didn't find the solution.

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made?

Comment: this.booking.item.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")

Comment: it should be `<br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before submitting to the API just run something like this:

```
str = str.replace('\n', '<br>');
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use the CSS to the element

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

No need to make a new function to processing that input.

Comment: Cleaner solution.